# C#/VSTO: Is there an event that fires reliably when data changes in a worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am aware of the `Worksheet.Change` event which ["Occurs when something changes in the Worksheet cells."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.change?view=vsto-2017) According to Microsoft. The problem is that this isn't true. It fires when you edit a cell, if you delete the contents of a cell, or when you delete or insert rows or columns.

But there are a number of ways a worksheet can change without triggering the event, for instance if data in a worksheet is sorted.

I figured out a way to keep track of when the Filter function is used and the user changes the sort column or direction. It involves periodically comparing worksheet properties to their previous values and it's awfully messy and hacky, but it works, so whatever.

But the Sort button in the Data tab eludes me because it doesn't seem to be tied to any `Worksheet` properties or events. The best solution I've come up with so far is to read and re-read blocks of cells periodically to manually check if anything changes. It's not at all satisfactory.

Please help.

On a side note, am I wrong in thinking Microsoft has more or less abandoned VSTO by now?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to understand VSTO you should have a look at then EXCEL object structure.

In Excel for example you can use a macro editor for recording different cases. After that you can see in the macro file what Excel did.

In VSTO you should be able to use nearly the same events. In your case, you can watch the **Workbook_SheetSelectionChange** - Event. 
If you want to know if anything changes in your Workbook, you can also handle the Workbook_BeforeClose - Event and check if the ActiveWorkbook.Saved - Method is true or false.

Here is a little example for the VSTO-Event for Workbook_BeforeClose
(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9f96e186-dddb-44a9-ac99-ab0ebef846b3/save-workbook-event-in-excel-vsto-application?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Workbook.SheetSelectionChange is fired when a new cell or cell range is selected, not when the actual contents of the worksheet change. To react to that you'd use the Worksheet.Change (or Workbook.SheetChange) event which is supposed to fire whenever the contents of a sheet are changed. It just doesn't if the changes are caused by Excel's own functions like the sort tool or the filter functionality.

And as for Workbook.BeforeClose, it doesn't help for doing any realtime work, such as analyzing a spreadsheet as it is being edited. (Which is the project I'm currently working on.)

Answer (score 0):

look into calculate event of worksheet,or if you are using named range use change event of that specified range.